# Why DIV > A > TEXT + DIV > A > TEXT 2 doesn't work?

Tags: html, css

It really confuses me. Why the second example doesn't work?

This works fine - div gets outlined on hover.

```css
a:hover > div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
        TEXT
        <div>
            TEXT 2
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

As soon as I add A into the div. Div doesn't get outlined anymore?

```css
a:hover > div {
    outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#">
        TEXT
        <div>
            <a href="">TEXT 2</a>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

Is there is something with HTML standards?

**UPD:** Thanks for answers, guys, actually I didn't realize I nest anchors. Somehow it was not obvious to my brain.

Comment: You’re not supposed to nest anchor elements inside each other. It doesn’t make sense.

Comment: I don't believe you can have nested anchor tags. If you click on the inner one, which link do you open?

Comment: Why is this post downvoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you can't use intertwined `a` tag.

The browser compile your html code differently.

[image]

Try replacing
`<a href="#">`
with
`<div>`